# JavaFX - Tableview filter from a Textfield

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, filtering, fxml

Folks,

Hopefully someone might be able to advise me on the following:
I have a TableView called packetTable. This tableView and its TableColumns get populated from a class called Packet. This is working correctly.

I have now added a TextField called protoFilterField. The idea is that when text is entered into this TextField that the TableView will filter based upon the users input.

I have my TextField OnAction method set as Initialize() method. When I run the application, my TableView initially populates fully, which is correct. However if I enter any text into my new TextField and hit return, it clears out my TableView completely. I have tried entering 'tcp' as my text & this should be valid & return numerous records into my filtered search.

Can anyone spot where I am going wrong? Any advise would be appreciated.

```
public class PacketOverviewController {
    @FXML
    private TableView<Packet> packetTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Packet, String> StartTimeColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Packet, Double> DurColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Packet, String> ProtoColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Packet, String> SrcAddrColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Packet, String> SportColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Packet, String> DirColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Packet, String> DstAddrColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Packet, String> DportColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Packet, String> StateColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Packet, String> sTosColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Packet, String> dTosColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Packet, String> SrcBytesColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Packet, String> LabelColumn;

    @FXML
    private TextField SummaryCountField;

    @FXML
    private TextField protoFilterField;

    private ObservableList<Packet> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();  //NEW TEST


    // Reference to the main application.
    private MainApp mainApp;

    /**
     * The constructor.
     * The constructor is called before the initialize() method.
     */
    public PacketOverviewController() {

    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        StartTimeColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().StartTimeProperty());
        DurColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().DurProperty().asObject());
        ProtoColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().ProtoProperty());
        SrcAddrColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().SrcAddrProperty());
        SportColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().SportProperty());
        DirColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().DirProperty());
        DstAddrColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().DstAddrProperty());
        DportColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().DportProperty());
        StateColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().StateProperty());
        sTosColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().sTosProperty());
        dTosColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().dTosProperty());
        //SrcBytesColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().SrcBytesProperty().asObject());
        LabelColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().LabelProperty());


        //NEW FILTERED FUNCTIONALITY
        FilteredList<Packet> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(data, p -> true);    //NEW TEST
        //FILTER ON THE PROTOCOL FIELD
        protoFilterField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            filteredData.setPredicate(packet -> {
                if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()){
                    return true;
                }
                System.out.println("filter test 1");
                String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();

                if (packet.getProto().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
        });

        SortedList<Packet> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);
        sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(packetTable.comparatorProperty());
        packetTable.setItems(sortedData);
        //END NEW FILTERED FUNCTIONALITY
    }

    public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
        this.mainApp = mainApp;

        packetTable.setItems(mainApp.getPacketData());

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `setMainApp(...)` before you load the FXML file? Otherwise I can't see how it would do any filtering at all (you replace the table's items list entirely when you call `setMainApp(...)`). The filtering you define in the `initialize()` method should work as soon as you type anything, not "when you press enter", as you state in the question. So I suspect there is some other code somewhere that is causing the data to vanish when an action event occurs on the text field. You should post a [MCVE] (create a new, complete, project with many fewer columns, and post it in your question).

Comment: I call setMainApp(...) from my MainApp.java when loading the FXML file.

Comment: "When loading". You obviously can't call it at the *same time* you call `FXMLLoader.load()`. Do you call it *before* calling `load()`, or *after* calling `load()`? The `initialize()` method is called as part of the `load` process, so if you call it after you are not using the filtered list in the table at all.

Comment: It is called after my load().

Comment: In that case you need `data.setAll(mainApp.getPacketData())` instead of the line you currently have. (But I still suspect you have something else wrong that you haven't posted.)

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much James.

Answer (score 0):

Needed data.setAll(mainApp.getPacketData()) instead of the line that I currently have. (packetTable.setItems(mainApp.getPacketData()))

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really posted enough code in the question to answer this, but from the comments and some assumptions, I guess you are loading the FXML with code that looks like

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/path/to/some/file.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();

PacketOverviewController controller = loader.getController();
controller.setMainApp(this);
```

The problem then would be that you set the table's items to the filtered list in the `initialize()` method, which is called as part of the `load()` process. You then *subsequently* call `setMainApp(...)` which actually replaces those items with a list defined in the main application class (which is not a good design, btw).

You should update the list underlying the filtered list instead:

```
public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
    this.mainApp = mainApp;

    // packetTable.setItems(mainApp.getPacketData());
    data.setAll(mainApp.getPacketData());
}
```